# Update Core Data inside my model class

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

What are the best practices on where to update my Core Data?

The first guy who worked on this project I'm working right now created all the Core Data related functions inside the ViewController, but I wanted to declare them inside the model classes (NSManagedObject subclass) to separate concerns.

The main function is a AFNetworking postPath that calls a web service and returns an array of objects to add/edit/delete. What I did was create a class method and do this AFNetwork call inside it:

```
+ (void)updateEbooksListWithSuccessBlock:(void (^)())successBlock andFailureBlock:(void (^)())failureBlock {
NSURL *url = urlSchema (urlWebServices, @"");
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSString *postPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ws-ebooks-lista.php"];

[httpClient postPath:postPath parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    if ([operation isKindOfClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]]) {
        NSDictionary *result = [[responseObject objectFromJSONData] retain];
        bool success = statusDoRetornoDoWebService(result); //Function that checks if the return was successful 

        //Configura o Core Data
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSManagedObjectContext *localManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [localManagedObjectContext setParentContext:[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ebooks" inManagedObjectContext:localManagedObjectContext];
        NSPredicate *filterPredicate;

        [request setEntity:entity];

        if (success) {
            NSArray *ebookInfos = [result objectForKey:@"saida"];
            Ebooks *ebook;
            NSManagedObject *objectInsert;

            for (NSDictionary* ebookInfo in ebookInfos) {

                filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ebooks_id == %@",[ebookInfo valueForKey:@"id_ebook"]];
                [request setPredicate:filterPredicate];
                ebook = [[localManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];
                objectInsert  = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:localManagedObjectContext];

                if (ebook) {
                    if (![[ebookInfo valueForKey:@"excluido"] isEmpty]) {
                        //Delete Ebook
                    } else {
                        //Update Ebook
                    }
                } else {
                    //Add Ebook
                }

                if (![localManagedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                    //Log Error
                }

                [objectInsert release];
            }

        }

        [request release];
        [localManagedObjectContext release];
    }

    [successBlock invoke];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //Failure

    [failureBlock invoke];
}];}
```

And it works fine while the app is running, but if I close it (through Xcode) and open it again, the changes aren't saved. I tried not using the "parent context" way and just using the AppDelegate managed object context (since AFNetworking callbacks always runs on the main queue) but no success: the data is not persisted. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong? Is it bad practice? Should I leave everything in the View Controller the way it was?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a bad idea to have too much logic that ultimately relates to your *data model* into your entity classes. These tasks simply do not belong there. The entity classes should focus only on what they encapsulate: the entity instances themselves.

To illustrate: think of a class that represents a number (like `NSNumber`). It think it is not convenient to extend it to give you, say, an array of all even numbers within a certain limits, or the nth member of the Fibonacci series. It seems unsound to have a number class be responsible for saving itself to a file, or retrieving information from the web.

For these and similar reasons, I believe the fetching and saving of Core Data entities belongs into controllers, not entity classes. Remember, one of the basic ideas behind the MVC (model-view-controller) pattern is that the controller manipulates the model or asks it for information, not that the model manipulates itself.

I speculate that your troubles are derived mainly from not separating the various functional aspects of your application sufficiently (data model, persistence, network operations, user interactions).

Comment: I liked your explanation, but it got me thinking: what if, in my example, I needed to update the Ebooks list in another (unrelated) Controller? Say a side menu that has a shortcut to this list. Would I repeat the code?

Comment: No, you should have a class `EbookManager` that takes care of this logic. Use a singleton to encapsulate this functionality.

Comment: Allright cool, I accepted your answer. Just a quick follow-up: what if I need to create a function to download the ebook and save to core data the download info. Should that be done on the ViewController or the Model class? It seems reasonable to put it in the model class since it's dealing straight with the entity.

Comment: Absolutely not the model class. Downloading should be done by your "DownloadEngine" class. Once it has solved the problem of downloading, it can create a new eBook instance and save it. There is no role here for your entity class.

Comment: What would that DownloadEngine class be? Just a class to deal with downloading files for my app? Do you have any sources I could do some further reading? Thank you very much for taking your time to help me, Mundi. :)

Comment: It would be your own class where you download your data in the usual way (I use NSURLConnection, but apparently you prefer third party software). It can then save itself to Core Data and either notify the UI via NSNotification to update itslef, or rely on NSFetchedResultsController delegate which will detect the changes in Core Data automatically.

Answer (score 1):

ugh... what I would do is make very naked `NSManagedObject` subclasses... then extend them with [categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html), that way when you regenerate your classes from the updated model you don't have to try to merge in all of your custom logic.

also the custom logic belongs in the model, the model contains the category or class extension.

so take that crap out of the View Controllers and put it in an easily maintainable category or several categories if it is warranted.

Comment: I agree with you, but wouldn't extending my NSManagedObject classes give me the same result I'm having right now (not persisting data)?

Comment: @dccarmo your problems with lack of persistence are some other issue, either your persistence manager isn't writing the file to the disk, or the context isn't getting saved, or it presents an error and you are ignoring it, I haven't tried to run your code.